# Replacing WaitForMultipleObjects in Qt

Tags: qt, winapi, porting

I am not familar with WINAPI, and I am looking for a way to replace WaitForMultipleObjects used in one example I'm porting to Qt by anything using Qt only. Is it possible?

**EDIT: (Providing more information as requested in comments)**

A 3rd party API provides an array of events:

```
HANDLE  m_hEv[MAX_EV];
```

In an endles-loop of a thread, the program waits for the events like this:

```
WaitForMultipleObjects(m_EvMax, m_hEv, FALSE ,INFINITE )
```

The `HANDLE` type seems to be void*. 
So I wonder, if any Qt class could observe m_hEv for changes and unlock thread execution.

Comment: Can you give more context about what WaitForMultipleObjects for winapi does? I know Qt but not winapi

Comment: What exactly are you using `WaitForMultipleObject` for in your program?

Comment: @jdi: It allows you to wait for all or any events in a group to occur (e.g. waiting for a group of threads to finish).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no simple way of porting `WaitForMultipleObjects` outside WinAPI. WinAPI has an "advantage" of that all lockable resources (sockets, files, processes) provide the same generic non-typesafe `HANDLE`, which is your `void*`. Unlike other platforms which have different ways of locking and signalling per the type of resource, the event handling in WinAPI is largely independent of the resources. Then a generic function like `WaitForMultipleObjects` can exist, which doesn't need to care who produced the HANDLEs. So you'll have to understand what the code is trying to do and mimic it differently per scenario.

The biggest difference is in `WaitForMultipleObjects` third parameter, which is **FALSE** in your case. Which means that the it will exit waiting as soon as any single event of the waiting array will happen. That is the easier scenario and can be replaced with a `QWaitCondition`.

1. Instead of `m_hEv`, you will pass a `QWaitCondition*` into the code which signals the event (most probably via WinAPI `SetEvent(m_hEv[x])`)
2. Instead of WaitForMultipleObjects, do `QWaitCondition::wait()`.
3. Instead of `SetEvent()`, do `QWaitCondition::wakeOne()`.

Would the third parameter be **TRUE**, then the WinAPI code waits until ALL m_hEv events are signalled. The established name for such functionality is a **synchronization barrier** and it can be simulated with `QEventCondition` too, but does not come out of the Qt box. I never needed to do any myself, but SO has some ideas how to do it:

[Qt synchronization barrier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637374/qt-synchronization-barrier)

Comment: Thank you very much for this wonderful explatation of how WaitFor...Object works. I was failed to understand, how void* could be evaluated as a thread lock. Yet I've understood it. I've ordered all the books suggested by Qt (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads.html#recommended-reading). Seems, the understanding of underlying platform is inevitable in some cases. Concerning my intent, seems like there is only way to introduce an additional layer and to wait for events on Linux and Win in platform-specific code.

Comment: IMHO, you won't need a Linux specific nonportable code. Qt is very close in threading philosophy to Linux, so there shouldn't be such severe porting problems as with WinAPI. And once you finish your WinAPI platform-specific code, i bet its interface will look very much like QWaitCondition :)

Comment: I don't see how you can wait for multiple QMutex objects in a QWaitCondition, the wait function only seems to accept one mutex. Is there a way to have it accept multiple QMutex'es?

Comment: @Stormenet: if you wanted QWaitCondition to accept multiple QMutexes from one call, what would you expect it to do then? You can't hold one thread more than once - you would get a deadlock. The wait function surely accepts only one QMutex. You are expected to call it from as many threads as you want, with different QMutex instances. That's the whole point of wait condition.

Comment: I think I understand how to use it now. Instead of waiting for multiple objects (events) eg ProducerItemsAvailable and ThreadStopRequest you just wait for one QWaitCondition and trigger it whilst keep track for what reason the wakeOne was triggered and take the correct action. Is this about right?

Comment: Now i understand your previous comment. You wanted to have multiple "wakers" and you thought it's done by taking QMutexes. Those are just for the "waiters" and there is only one waking point without referring to any mutex. There is no direct analogy of WaitForMultipleObjects in Qt. You could roll your own class which would register multiple QWaitConditions, but for the simple case, yes a thread-safe flag setting before firing wakeOne is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

WaitForMultipleObjects is a kind of generic function that works with many things: threads, processes, mutexes, etc. Qt is an OOP library where every class exposes the operations it supports. So the equivalent operation in Qt depends on what class you're using. For example, with threads, use QThread::wait. With mutexes, use QMutex::lock.