# Force threads to wait for other threads to complete their jobs before going further?

Tags: qt, qthread

suppose I have a thread class with `run` method like this :

```
void run()
{
   while(1){
     first_job();
     //__Syncthreads();
     second_job();
   }
}
```

I have 3 threads and I want all of them do `first_job()` and wait for other to accomplish `first_job()` before they going for `second_job()`
I know that there is something called `QWaitCondition` but I think I need an extra thread. Am I true?

Comment: That synchronization method is called Barrier. See e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637374/qt-synchronization-barrier and no, no extra thread is needed.